# How to make Fluent API configuration work with MVC client side validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I prefer working with Fluent API configuration to DataAnnotation because I want to separate model from data access.

I have tried in MVC, Fluent API does not work with client side validation. Shortly speaking, is there a simple way to make Fluent API works with client side validation as DataAnnotation can do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No. Fluent API is just mapping - correct. Data annotations are both mapping and validation - wrong. Data annotations are one of the worst features of EF code first because when used this way they couple persistence with presentation and validation logic.

Advice: don't use EF entities for presentation. Use special view models with data annotations and let your controller prepare view models from entities and vice-versa. Soon or later you will find situations where your validation is not 1:1 with your mapping or where your view needs more or less data than provided in entity type. Use view models and these situations will be handled by them.

Comment: Why does EF even need mappings like "HasMaxLength"? If the value is longer, SQL server will reject it if write is attempted, and it does not matter on reads since `string` type does not have a length limitation. So what is this mapping actually for?

Comment: I know this is an old question but thought I'd add for future readers.  One reason is if you use code first to then create the database, the fluent api/data annotations are then used in building the create table statements, where it needs to know the desired length and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for a while today, and this is not strictly client validation as it requires a round trip, but it does allow you to benefit from the Validation summary and messages helpers in the standard template. Within your controller action method you simply wrap your `SaveChanges()` call in a try - catch and add the resulting Errors to the `ModelState` as follows:

```
try {

    //This does not pick up fluent validation failures
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entity.Add(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Users want to create loads of my entities without seeing the index...
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

} catch (DbEntityValidationException e) {

    //Log errors
    foreach (var result in e.EntityValidationErrors) {
        foreach(var error in result.ValidationErrors){
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

}

//return to view with current model + validation errors 
return View(entity)
```

This would of course require a bit more work if you are saving multiple entities here.

Of course using a View Model objects as Ladislav suggests would be the correct approach, however I have used this to support a test UI requested for downstream systems integration testing ahead of schedule...