# Is Entity Framework Dataannotations bad for DDD and separation of concerns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design

I've been working quite som time now to learn how to implement DDD, IoC and ensure there is a separation of concerns in my application. I'm also trying to get in to the way of Test First Development.

Somehow Entity Framework gives med some trouble. I have a domain project that keeps my domain objects (many of them POCO classes now, but with some behavior). It's legacy code, and I try to refactor it, but MVC realies heavily on Dataannotations for validation.

The datavalidation-attributes is set on the domain objects, which ties them  to the entity framework. Most instructional videos and documentation on EF also uses a lot of attributes on the domain objects.

**So I wonder if this is really a good thing?**

I like the idea of many of the attributes, but the consequence of putting them on the domian objects makes me feel that entity framework is the core of the application and not the domain objects.

Do you have any tips on solving this, or is this how it should be?

**UPDATE:**

The suggested answers below led me to this post answered by [Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894367/how-to-make-fluent-api-configuration-work-with-mvc-client-side-validation)

To me that probably sounds like the best way to go if it solves my problem. He also points out the same problem I have with the attributes in the domain layer.

Comment: Yes, Ladislav's answer about using View models is the correct one.  You should not be mixing your domain and presentation logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you feel better with [Code First Fluent API Validations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, I would. Was not aware that I could put validation rules in the fluent API. However there is still quite a bit of client side validation that will not recognise this. Maybe I could use validation-annotations on the view-model? I'll have to check that out.

Comment: It depends on your application. The application I did used ajax for most of the forms. I just used serverside validation, but it feels like clienside validation. I was never very lucky with clientside validation in combination with localisation.

Comment: Well, the UI is also legacy and some is ajax and som is not. However, it's possible for me to change that. Server side validation is a must anyway, so I will put the validation in the Fluent APi for EF but I will also use ViewModels and put annotations there.

Answer (score 2):

Some attributes are relevant to EF and MVC - attributes that describe your class. A required field, minimum and maximum lengths, etc... If you really want to separate everything, I'd keep these attributes on your domain objects, put database stuff (foreign keys, etc...) in FluentAPI and MVC stuff (display names, etc...) on the view model.

If MVC 4 happens to support FluentAPI (I'm using MVC 3, which doesn't, don't know about 4), you should definitely use it.

Comment: I'm migrating to mvc 4 now, but haven't checked that myself. If it does, that's where I'll put it. I can agree that as long as the attributes describes the class and is not keys, foreign keys that relates to the DB it's not the biggets problem. I just feel that if I change EF or something changes there, I should not need to make changes in my domain layer. That seems to be a bad design...